# Inset div 10px inside parent div of fixed size?

Tags: css, html

Given a parent div of unknown or variable size and a child div, how can the child div be inset 10px from each side of the parent div?

[image: Diagram]

I want to avoid using `position` and if I add `width:100%; height:100%; margin:10px;` it causes the child to stick out of the right and bottom by 20px.

To clarify, the child needs to fit inside the parent div. The parent div can't grow to fit the child. The parent is of unknown size.

Comment: There are couple of ways to achieve that, but they may not fit your needs. You should post relevant code or provide an online demo of what you've done so far. What are the requirements?

Comment: I have a feeling you're not sharing all the info, as I doubt you haven't tried setting the width of the parent to 20px larger than the child and set the child to `margin:10px`, which would be the simplest way to fix this...

Comment: He's looking for the `padding` property, not for the `margin` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use CSS `box-sizing`, that will include padding inside the width. 
As you said...

> it causes the child to stick out of the right and bottom by 20px.

...this will prevent that from happening.

```
#parent, #child {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
     box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Alternatively, you set a 10px padding on the `#parent`, then you set the `#child` to 100% width and height.

Comment: +1 I was about to post an answer, anyway **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/TTUVL/3/)**. It's worth noting that `border-box` value is supported in **IE8+**

Comment: @Keavon One of the requirements would be browsers compatibility. Please consider providing more details in the future.

Comment: I'm not very worried about browser support for my case, but I'll be sure to include that for the future.

Comment: here you can find out about the browser support for `box-sizing` http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 0):

```
div#child {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#parent {
    padding: 10px;
}

#child {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/TTUVL/2/).

Comment: @downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining your downvote.  Why is this not a good answer?